# global variable in jquery function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables, global-variables

I´ve defined a global variable in this function, but it doesn't work. If I define the variable in the function it works, but I want it global.

```
var currentpage = 1;

    $(document).ready(function(){

      function checkpage(currentpage) { 
        if (currentpage == 1) {
          $(".text_nav").html("some text");
        };
      }

      checkpage();

    });
```

Why do I want it?
Because I want to decrease the variable on click to do something

```
$( "#button" ).click(function() {
  currentpage += 1;
});

//check currentpage variable again (who?)
            if (currentpage == 2) {
              $(".text_nav").html("some other text");
            };
```

Comment: are you looking for something like this http://jsfiddle.net/ftjc1c7w/?

Comment: What do you mean by *but it dont work*

Comment: You need to remove ```currentpage``` from ```function checkpage(currentpage) {```, or call ```checkpage(currentpage)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does work, you didn't send anything into the function, do this:

```
 checkpage(currentpage);
```

The `currentpage` in the function is a parameter, it's a local variable for that function and is separate from the global variable. Or simply remove the parameter if you don't need it:

```
function checkpage() { // Other than 'checkpage(currentpage)'
   ...
}
```